# xmlHttpRequest() having CORS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a simple program to get contents of an xml file which I hosted on google drive

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    contentType: "text/plain",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },
    //headers: {
    //    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
    //    //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    //},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    },
    success: function (xml) {
        console.log(xml);
    },
    error: function () {

    }

});
```

I am getting

```
"OPTIONS https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7clmSyh5-q3QWZpWW8xZnJfa1k 405 (Method Not Allowed)"<br/>
```

AND

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7clmSyh5-q3QWZpWW8xZnJfa1k. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."
```

as ERRORS. 
I searched a lot about CORS and headers for this issue but couldn't make my code work. Please can anyone help me.

Comment: docs.google.com does not support CORS.

Comment: but I am able to put an image in <image src=url> where url is image hosted on google drive. Then how is it possible that image can be retrived but xml file cannot.

Comment: An `<img>` loaded in from off-site will be fetched because it's not going via a script. Anything done in script has security restrictions (so you don't e.g. load up someones email & bank pages). _CORS_ headers need to be sent in the _server's_ **response**. This is so the responder has control over who sees what, not the requester. This type of security is implemented by the browser, so don't rely on it as a security mechanism if you control a server - someone could do it with a hacked browser, for example.

Comment: thanks a lot @Paul S , completely got your point. Really appreciate your precious time and help.